# Find radius of circle in plane geometry problem

Tags: geometry

I am given the following problem. Considering the geometric configuration shown below, find the radius of the circle knowing that $AB = 2, AC = 4 AP = 2\sqrt{3}$ and the angles $B\hat{A}P$ and $P\hat{A}C$ are equal.

First I tried to draw the segments $BP$ and $PC$ and using the cosines theorem i calculated their length. Then tried using the ptolemaic theorem, wishing that unknown parameters would go away; if I calculate $BC$ I can easily calculate radius.

can anyone give me some help?

[image: 1]

Comment: How is it possible that three chords originate from $A$ and the intermediate chord $AP$ is shorter while extreme chords $AB, AC$ are longer?

Comment: @MyMolecules i drew this picture, sorry ;dd

Comment: Is it $AC=4AP$ or $AC=4$?

Comment: You can compute $\cos\alpha$ from $BP=PC$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca yeah, i forgot that BP=PC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $AC=a$, $CP=b$, $PB=c$, $BA=d$, $AP=f$, and $BC=e$.  Key insight here is that $b=c$ by the Law of Sine.  From $ac+bd=ef$ and $c=b$ we get
$$b(a+d)=ef$$
The Law of Cosine then gives a quadratic in $\cos(\alpha)$, which is quite easily solved by
$$\cos(\alpha)=\frac{a(a+d)}{2df}\text{ or }
\frac{d(a+d)}{2df},$$
assuming wlog $a\ge d$.

This gives after some tedious calculations
$$R=\frac{f}{\sqrt2\cdot\sin(2\alpha)}.$$

Comment: Thanks so much!!!